# embed raise ValidationError in wtform custom validation messages

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to check the useremail already exist in JSON data using the wtf validation. I made a function which check the user exist but I have the problem with raise ValidatioError. I want to embed it with the StringField message for example when the submit the form without putting data it get errors like this field is required same way when the user enters the email which is alredy exist it show the error message

flash work for me but I want to embed it with the StringFields error

### I tried

```
def check_user(self,email):
        """User name check in data base"""
        if email != users:
            raise ValidationError('Email already registered.')
```

which work but crash the application

```
def check_user(self,email):
        """User name check in data base"""
        if email != users:
            self.email.errors.append("Email already registered")
```

not display any error or feedback

### this is the complete files

`form.py`

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo,ValidationError
import json
from flask import redirect,request, url_for, flash


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators = [
                           DataRequired(message=('Please enter your name!')),
                           Length(min=3, max=20)
    ])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators = [
                        DataRequired(message=('Please enter email address!')),
                        Email(),
                        Length(min=6)

    ])
    password = PasswordField('Password',
                            validators = [
                            DataRequired(message=('Please enter the password')),
                            Length(min=6,max=20),

    ])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

    # function which check the user already exist in database
    def user_already_exit(self, email):
        """Email validation."""
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')

users = {
    "aheer": {
        "username": "aheer",
        "email": "aheer@gmail.com",
        "password": "example",
        "bio": "Some guy from the internet"
    },
    "majid": {
        "username": "majid",
        "email": "clarissa@icloud.com",
        "password": "example",
        "bio": "Sweet potato is life"
    }
}

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

    def check_user(self,email):
        """User name check in data base"""
        if email != users:
            raise ValidationError('Email already registered.')


    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators = [
                        DataRequired(message=('Please enter email address!')),
                        Email(),
                        Length(min=6)
    ])
    password = PasswordField('Password',
                            validators = [
                            DataRequired(message=('Please enter the password')),
                            Length(min=6,max=20),

    ])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

`login.html`

```
{% extends "public/templates/public_template.html" %}
{% import "macros/input_macros.html" as im %}
{% block title %} User Login {% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center pt-3 pb-3">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="text-center">Welcome Back!</h4>
                      <hr>
                        <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
                            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                              {{ im.input(form.email.label) }}
                                {% if form.email.errors %}
                                  {{ im.input(form.email,placeholder='aheer@gmail.com',class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                  {% else %}
                                  {{ im.input(form.email,placeholder='aheer@gmail.com',class="form-control") }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              {{ im.input(form.password.label) }}
                                {% if form.password.errors %}
                                  {{ im.input(form.password,class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                  {% else %}
                                  {{ im.input(form.password,class="form-control") }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                               {{ form.remember(class="form-check-input") }}
                               {{ form.remember.label(class="form-check-label") }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" name="submit" value="Next">
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <p class="text-center">Don't have an account ? <a class="ml-1" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Sign Up</a></p>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

`view.py`

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    get_user_input = request.form
    form = LoginForm(get_user_input)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.check_user(form.email.data):
            flash(f'Welcome {form.email.data}!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            user = users[form.email.data]
    # if request.method == "POST":
    #     get_user_input = request.form
    #     username = get_user_input.get("name")
    #     password = get_user_input.get("password")
    #
    #     if not username in users:
    #         print("Username not found")
    #         return redirect(request.url)
    #     else:
    #         user = users[username]
    #
    #     if not password == user["password"]:
    #         print("Incorrect password")
    #         return redirect(request.url)
    #     else:
    #         session["USERNAME"] = user["username"]
    #         print("session username set")
    #         return redirect(url_for('admin'))
    return render_template("public/login.html",form=form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. `self.email.errors` is tuple of Validation errors. So you should do this:

```py
from wtforms import ValidationError
...
def check_user(self,email):
        """User name check in data base"""
        if email != users:
            self.email.errors += (ValidationError("Email already registered"),)
```

It creates tuple from single ValidationError and adds it to your errors.